# int to short Assignment failing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've encountered some strange behaviour when trying to promote a **short** to an **int** where the upper 2 bytes are 0xFFFF after promotion. AFAIK the upper bytes should always remain 0. See the following code:

```
    unsigned int test1 = proxy0->m_collisionFilterGroup;
    unsigned int test2 = proxy0->m_collisionFilterMask;
    unsigned int test3 = proxy1->m_collisionFilterGroup;
    unsigned int test4 = proxy1->m_collisionFilterMask;

    if( test1 & 0xFFFF0000 || test2 & 0xFFFF0000 || test3 & 0xFFFF0000 || test4 & 0xFFFF0000 )
    {
        std::cout << "test";
    }
```

The values of the involved variables is once **cout** is hit is:

[image: Strange Promotion]

Note the two highlighted values. I also looked at the disassembly which also looks fine to me:

[image: Disassembly]

My software is targeting x64 compiled with VS 2008 SP1. I also link in an out of the box version of Bullet Physics 2.80. The proxy objects are bullet objects.

The proxy class definition is as follows (with some functions trimmed out):

```
    ///The btBroadphaseProxy is the main class that can be used with the Bullet broadphases. 
///It stores collision shape type information, collision filter information and a client object, typically a btCollisionObject or btRigidBody.
ATTRIBUTE_ALIGNED16(struct) btBroadphaseProxy
{

BT_DECLARE_ALIGNED_ALLOCATOR();

    ///optional filtering to cull potential collisions
    enum CollisionFilterGroups
    {
            DefaultFilter = 1,
            StaticFilter = 2,
            KinematicFilter = 4,
            DebrisFilter = 8,
            SensorTrigger = 16,
            CharacterFilter = 32,
            AllFilter = -1 //all bits sets: DefaultFilter | StaticFilter | KinematicFilter | DebrisFilter | SensorTrigger
    };

    //Usually the client btCollisionObject or Rigidbody class
    void*   m_clientObject;
    short int m_collisionFilterGroup;
    short int m_collisionFilterMask;
    void*   m_multiSapParentProxy;      
    int         m_uniqueId;//m_uniqueId is introduced for paircache. could get rid of this, by calculating the address offset etc.

    btVector3   m_aabbMin;
    btVector3   m_aabbMax;

    SIMD_FORCE_INLINE int getUid() const
    {
        return m_uniqueId;
    }

    //used for memory pools
    btBroadphaseProxy() :m_clientObject(0),m_multiSapParentProxy(0)
    {
    }

    btBroadphaseProxy(const btVector3& aabbMin,const btVector3& aabbMax,void* userPtr,short int collisionFilterGroup, short int collisionFilterMask,void* multiSapParentProxy=0)
        :m_clientObject(userPtr),
        m_collisionFilterGroup(collisionFilterGroup),
        m_collisionFilterMask(collisionFilterMask),
        m_aabbMin(aabbMin),
        m_aabbMax(aabbMax)
    {
        m_multiSapParentProxy = multiSapParentProxy;
    }
}
;
```

I've never had this issue before and only started getting it after upgrading to 64 bit and integrating bullet. The only place I am getting issues is where bullet is involved so I suspect the issue is related to that somehow, but I am still super confused about what could make assignments between primitive types not behave as expected.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's just sign-extension integer promotion. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: The shorts are signed, right? And pretty negative, too.

Comment: Yes the shorts there are signed, however I just double checked and signededness makes no difference. The issue keeps occurring if i remove unsigned from the ints.

Comment: Of course. -1 by any other type will still be -1. What are you *expecting* to see?

Comment: To be sure: -1 as a short: `0xFFFF`. -1 as an int: `0xFFFFFFFF`. -1 as an unsigned int: ditto.

Comment: And you can't make the shorts in the function unsigned? In that case, the solution is to cast them to `unsigned short` before assigning them to the ints. `unsigned int test1 = static_cast<unsignes short>(proxy0->m_collisionFilterGroup);`

Comment: I was expecting to see 0xc26b become 0x0000c26b. It seems as though this will only be the case with positive values...

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE - Assignment and promotion are designed to preserve the *value* and not the bits, because this is what most people expect.

Comment: When assigning a negative number to unsigned, the value will change anyway. Unsigned ints cannot have the value -15765, it's that simple! Cast to unsigned short first, so you will have the value 49771 to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requesting a conversion from signed to unsigned. This is pretty straigth-forward:

- Your source value is `-1`. Since the type is `short int`, on your platform that has bits `0xFFFF`.
- The target type is `unsigned int`. `-1` cannot be expressed as an unsigned int, but the conversion rule is defined by the standard: Pick the positive value that's congruent to `-1` modulo 2<sup>*N*</sup>, where *N* is the number of value bits of the unsigned type.

  On your platform, `unsigned int` has 32 value bits, so the modular representative of `-1` modulo 2<sup>32</sup> is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

If your own imaginary rules where to apply, you would want the result `0x0000FFFF`, which is 65535, and not related to −1 in any obvious or useful way.

If you *do* want that conversion, you must perform the modular wrap-around on the short type manually:

```
short int mo = -1;
unsigned int weird = static_cast<unsigned short int>(mo);
```

**Nutshell:** C++ is about *values*, not about *representations*.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK the upper bytes should always remain 0

When *promoting from short to int* **arithmetic shift** (also called **signed shift**) is used,
to answer you question it`s enough to know that it is performed by extension of greatest byte value on number of added bytes;

*example:*

```
short b;
int a = b; /* here promotion is performed, mechanism of it can be described by following bitwise operation: */
a = b >> (sizeof(a) - sizeof(b)); // arithmetic shift performed
```

important to notice that in memory of computer representation of signed and unsigned values can be the same, the only difference in commands generated by compiler:

example:

```
unsigned short i = -1 // 0xffff
short j = 65535 // 0xffff
```

so actually *signed/unsigned doesn`t matter for result on promotion*, arithmetic shift is performed in both cases